Does $\mathrm{Trace}(D^{-1}TD)=\mathrm{Trace}(T)$ hold for unbounded operators?
It is a problem that comes from Alain Connes' article Non-commutative Differential Geometry. In the proof of Corollary 2 in Part I, Section 6, we need a property that $\mathrm{Trace}(T-D^{-1}TD)=\mathrm{Trace}(D^{-1}TD-T)$ for an unbounded operator $ D $.
The original article assumes that $ H=H^+\oplus H^- $ is a $ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $-graded Hilbert space, $ D=\begin{bmatrix} & D_2 \\ D_1 & \end{bmatrix} $ is a (possibly unbounded) self-adjoint operator, and he claims that for $ T\in\mathcal B(H) $, one has
$$ \mathrm{Trace}_{H^-}(T-D_1TD_1^{-1})=\mathrm{Trace}_{H^+}(D_1^{-1}TD_1-T). $$
Is that true for the original case?
Moreover, I wonder if $ \mathrm{Trace}(D^{-1}TD)=\mathrm{Trace}(T) $ holds for an unbounded operator $ D $ such that $ D^{-1}TD $ is trace-class.
Any help will be sincerely appreciated!
